# Wrong document gets updated when using updateDoc from Firebase/Firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I use prop drilling to pass down the id value of the document, but every time I click on a document to update it using updateDoc, the same document gets updated(always the latest one added), not the one I clicked on. I don't understand why the unique IDs don't get passed down correctly to the function, or whether that's the problem. I use deleteDoc this way and it's working perfectly.   Any help will be appreciated.

This is where I get the id value from

```js
 const getPosts = useCallback(async (id) => {
    const data = await getDocs(postCollectionRef);
    setPosts(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    getPosts();
  }, [deletePost]);

  return (
    <div className={classes.home}>
      <ul className={classes.list}>
        {posts.map((post) => (
          <BlogCard
            key={post.id}
            id={post.id}
            title={post.title}
            image={post.image}
            post={post.post}
            date={post.date}
            showModal={showModal}
            setShowModal={setShowModal}
            deletePost={() => {
              deletePost(post.id);
            }}
            showUpdateModal={showUpdateModal}
            setShowUpdateModal={setShowUpdateModal}
          />
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
```

This is where I pass through the id value to the update modal component for each document:

```js
function BlogCard(props) {
  const [postIsOpen, setPostIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const modalHandler = () => {
    props.setShowModal((prevState) => {
      return (prevState = !prevState);
    });
  };

  const updateModalHandler = () => {
    props.setShowUpdateModal((prevState) => {
      return (prevState = !prevState);
    });
  };

  const handleView = () => {
    setPostIsOpen((prevState) => {
      return (prevState = !prevState);
    });
  };
  return (
    <>
      {props.showUpdateModal && (
        <UpdateModal
          showUpdateModal={props.showUpdateModal}
          setShowUpdateModal={props.setShowUpdateModal}
          id={props.id}
          title={props.title}
          image={props.image}
          post={props.post}
        />
      )}
      {props.showModal && (
        <DeleteModal
          showModal={props.showModal}
          setShowModal={props.setShowModal}
          deletePost={props.deletePost}
        />
      )}
      <div className={classes.blogCard} id={props.id}>
        <div className={classes.head}>
          <p className={classes.title}> {props.title}</p>
          <div className={classes.buttons}>
          <button className={classes.editButton} onClick={updateModalHandler}>
            Edit
          </button>
          <button className={classes.removeButton} onClick={modalHandler}>
            Delete
          </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <p className={classes.date}>{props.date}</p>
        <img src={props.image} alt="image" />
        {!postIsOpen ? (
          <p className={classes.viewHandler} onClick={handleView}>
            Show More
          </p>
        ) : (
          <p className={classes.viewHandler} onClick={handleView}>
            Show Less
          </p>
        )}
        {postIsOpen && <p className={classes.article}>{props.post}</p>}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default BlogCard;
```

Here I create the function to update and add the onclick listener

```js
function UpdateModal(props) {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState(props.title);
  const [image, setImage] = useState(props.image);
  const [post, setPost] = useState(props.post);

  const updateModalHandler = (prevState) => {
    props.setShowUpdateModal((prevState = !prevState));
  };

  const updatePost = async (id) => {
    const postDocRef = doc(db, "posts", id);
    props.setShowUpdateModal(false);
    try {
      await updateDoc(postDocRef, {
        title: title,
        image: image,
        post: post,
      });
    } catch (err) {
      alert(err);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div onClick={updateModalHandler} className={classes.backdrop}>
      <form onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()} className={classes.form}>
        <label htmlFor="title">Title</label>
        <input
          id="title"
          type="text"
          value={title}
          onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
        />
        <label htmlFor="image">Image(URL)</label>
        <input
          id="image"
          type="text"
          value={image}
          onChange={(e) => setImage(e.target.value)}
        />
        <label htmlFor="post">Post</label>
        <textarea
          id="post"
          cols="30"
          rows="30"
          value={post}
          onChange={(e) => setPost(e.target.value)}
        />
        <div className={classes.buttons}>
          <button className={classes.cancel} onClick={updateModalHandler}>Cancel</button>
          <button className={classes.update} onClick={() => updatePost(props.id)}>Update</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default UpdateModal;
```

This is the way my data is structured

[firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6349.png)

Comment: in your debugging, have you followed the chain of functions you created to see if all the details are correct at every stage? Have you identified where the issue arises, which one of your functions gets the wrong document

Comment: The correct id value is passed to the first child component, but when I pass the id to the second child component using id={props.id} the id has the value of the last document in the DB collection and not the same one it had in the first child component..